# New line character in Information Message in SAP v730 (via message class)?

Tags: message, abap

I want the Information Message to show two lines of text.
[image: image for Information message]

Can this be done using one message class statement. Ex.

```
MESSAGE i001(z56_myclass) WITH lv_cust_id.
```

I tried putting the string of the short text with characters `\n` `#` `\r` `\\n`  etc. but nothing worked. I don't know how to use long text editor for this particular requirement. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't control the message carriage return in `MESSAGE` statement.

You can try instead with the following information popup

```
call function 'POPUP_TO_INFORM'
  exporting
    titel         = 'Information'
    txt1          = 'Registration successful'
    txt2          = 'Customer Id is 0000001234'.
```

You have 4 text rows at your disposal (from txt1 to txt4).

[image]

Comment: You sure about that we can't achieve that via  "long text editor". Is `POP_TO_INFORM` the only way ?

Comment: Nope, `POPUP_TO_INFORM` is not the only way. I just proposed it because it's very similar to `MESSAGE TYPE I` statement. There're several other ways to show an information popup. See examples in **SE83->SAP Technology->Standard Dialogs->Display Text->Examples**